# IntelliJ produce bigger .jar then netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, lwjgl

is there anybody who can tell me why ItelliJ 12 produce two times bigger .jar file than netbeans from same code? In IntelliJ it's 98 MB vs 49 MB in NetBeans. I have been playing with properties but without any success. It's quite big project using LWJGL textures and 3D models. At the beginning I thought that intelliJ wrap all data textures and model together but it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you should compare jar (it's simple ZIP) file by file and folder by folder. You can use some compare software like WinMerge or many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the jar file by renaming it's extension to zip, or simply pressing `Ctrl+Page` Down. After that, you can compare the contents yourself. Probably IntelliJ includes some libraries, what Netbeans doesn't.

Comment: Interestin thing is that in .jar file are my models and textures but I also need them outside jar to my app have acces to then but anyway it is different problem. In InteliJ .jar are my models and textures twice i dont know why but they are. What happens if I simly delete those models form unpack jar and rename back to .jar ? :D

Comment: Instead of that, try to find out why INtelliJ adds those files twice. The source/resource folder is added probably twice.

But if you want, you can delete them - but you have to know, which one is the correct.

Answer (score 0):

Jar is a zip-file. First try to unpack and compare the sizes. Is it an issue of different compressions or diffierent content? If you are unable to find the difference, use some compare tool like beyond compare.